# Trigger Mysql Error Near the "

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a trigger and its giving me an error that I can't understand the reason of it. In my local server it works perfectly and in the remote doesn't. 
Both MySQL version are the same, MySQL 5.1.48.

Here is the trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualizar_cliente
BEFORE UPDATE ON cliente FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.password = "" THEN
    SET NEW.password = OLD.password;
ELSEIF NEW.password IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.password = (MD5(NEW.password));
END IF;
END
```

Here is the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: Which tool are you using to create the trigger?

Comment: @Raz I'm using SQLBuddy, PHPMyAdmin gives me 500Error in the remote server.

Comment: Are you able to access MySQL via the command line on this remote server?

Comment: Does SQLBuddy suport trigger manipulation? I can't find any info on their site or the release notes.

Comment: Your code seems correct so check if you can use PHPMyAdmin or direct connection (command line or from Workbench, if you have it installed in your machine).

Comment: I'm trying to get phpMyAdmin to work. Workbench i already give it a shot and nothing (Refused remote connection). As soon as i can get it to work i'll post the solution.

Comment: Many servers do not allow remote connections to MySQL, for security reasons. If you have ssh access, you could also go and connect to MySQL through it.

Comment: @Elkas, A few points on your query: 1: MD5 is broken, use SHA2 instead. 2: storing unsalted passwords in a DB is a bad idea, they will be decrypted in seconds using a rainbow table, use `SET NEW.password = SHA2(CONCAT(NEW.salt,NEW.password),512)` If you don't all that hard work in the trigger will be for nothing.

Comment: Your question is now more than a year old. How did you solve your issue? Or weren't you able to solve it in the end? What did you do as an alternative (if any)?

Comment: Actually I don't remember how i solved it and totally forgot to update this thread. I'll look for the answer in my database files and post it here. But i remember it was with MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 3):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER actualizar_cliente
BEFORE UPDATE ON cliente FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.password = "" THEN
    SET NEW.password = OLD.password;
ELSEIF NEW.password IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.password = (MD5(NEW.password));
END IF;
END

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and you probably need `IS NOT NULL`:

```
ELSEIF NEW.password IS NOT NULL THEN
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Error on the remote server: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER actualizar_cliente BEFORE UPDATE ON cliente FOR EAC' at line 1;

Comment: @Elkas: How are you running the code that tries to create the trigger?

Comment: @Elkas: Can you try with `= ''` instead of `= ""` ?

Comment: Same error mate... I'm Using SQLBuddy because PHPMyAdmin Returns 500 HTTP Error.